# How to detect if page doesn't allow to run external script via Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, feature-detection

I have a bookmark (Scheme REPL) and it doesn't work on the same pages because of Content Security Policy. But the error is in the console:

Example from GitHub:

> VM70:1 Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src github.githubassets.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Is there a way to detect that the page has CSP, so I could call an `alert()` with a message that this bookmark will not work on this page?